# How to merge multiple dictionaries into one when iterating over them one by one in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have list of dictionaries and I am trying to take each dictionary and group them into one dictionary after iterations. Is there a simple way of doing this. So far I am taking each dictionary after each iteration and appending them into a list. After  the iteration I get an output like below:

```
data = [{'disabled': False, 'id': '28394', 'self': 'www.google.com/28394', 'value': 'Tuesday'}, {'disabled': False, 'id': '23433', 'self': 'www.google.com/23433', 'value': 'Wednsday'}]
```

I would like to either convert it from a list to a single dictionary or somehow merge each dictionary into one like below.

```
data = {'disabled': False, 'id': '28394', 'self': 'www.google.com/28394', 'value': 'Tuesday', 'disabled': False, 'id': '23433', 'self': 'www.google.com/23433', 'value': 'Wednsday'}
```

Once I get that I want to add the dictionary using the dict() method that creates the empty dictionary to store those values.

Below is my code:

```
    elif(key == 'customfield_12951'):
             newDictionaryValues = []
             for issueItemInspection in oIssues['customfield']:
                 if(oIssues[key] == None):
                     values = {'value': None}
                     verificationDictNone = dict(values)
                     iterateDictIssues(verificationDictNone, listInner)
                 else:
                     if(len(oIssues[key]) == 1): 
                         values = issueItemInspection
                         verificationDict = dict(values)
                         iterateDictIssues(verificationDict, listInner) 
                     else:
                         values = issueItemInspection
                         newDictionaryValues.append(values)
                         print(newDictionaryValues)
                         verificationDictValues = dict(values)
                         iterateDictIssues(verificationDictValues, listInner)
```

There are multiple keys holding each dictionary and as you can see the issueItemInspection is carrying each individual dictionary. As each key dictionary gets appended I would like to merge these all into one or convert it from a list to a single dictionary. Right now it is a big list of dictionaries.

Comment: What you show as an example doesn't make sense. A dict contains each key at most once. You're showing repeated keys. For that you need a different data structure. Perhaps a list of pairs.  Or a dict from string keys to lists of values.

Comment: what you want is not possible in Python

Comment: Thank you al for your respsonses. Is it possible to remove the square brackets because once that happens I will have what I want. I asked because I am importing the values you see above into a dataframe. Everything works when there is only one dictionary, but when it is multiple dictionary with values they aren't importing incorrectly because of the multiple values that carry the list of dictionaries. That's why I wanted to convert the lists to a single dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand your point, but how about storing values with same keys into list?

```
from collections import defaultdict


data = [{'disabled': False, 'id': '28394', 'self': 'www.google.com/28394', 'value': 'Tuesday'}, {'disabled': False, 'id': '23433', 'self': 'www.google.com/23433', 'value': 'Wednsday'}]

d = defaultdict(list)

for dictionary in data:
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        d[k].append(v)


print(d)
```

Comment: Wow. This is what I was looking for thank you. @subjectivecamel

Answer (score 0):

You can't get to the requested data since your dictionnary have multiple key definition, it will only keep the last key value:

```
>>> dict_test = {'test': 1, 'test': 2}
>>> print(dict_test )
{'test': 2}
```